# Database Switching

Tags: php, mysql, database, replication

I am using mysql I want to use the database for example which is located in server A and when if my connection is lost from server A it should automatically switch to my localhost database and when it is connected again it should switch to server A.

Comment: Show some code please. What did you try? And why not always connect to `localhost` and have some mean to update its database from remote?

Comment: I think that you need cronjob or daemon which checks connections and changes config.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using just mysqli extensions, you should use this code to try to establish connection to server A first and if it fails fallback to server B, it will check connection to A server everytime the page loads.

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_init();
// set a timeout here, the time is in seconds, and this will affect both connections attempts (or more if you want).
$con->options(MYSQLI_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT, 2);    
if(!$con->real_connect("serverA.localdomain:3306","root","password","dbname"))
{
  /* server A not connected */      
  if(!$con->real_connect("serverB.localdomain:3306","root","password","dbname"))
  {
    die('Cannot connect to server A or B');
  } 
  else
  {
    echo 'Connection established to server B';
  }
}
else
{
  echo 'Connection established to server A';      
}

// do your stuff here using $con->...   

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: I think that it could be a solution. But i think that better to use [mysqli_real_connect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php) where you could define timeout.